# While i am trying to write SOQL query on Entitlement Standard object

Tags: apex, community

While i am trying to write SOQL query on Entitlement Standard object it is throughing the following error in Apex class.

The same query is working in developer console

List equipments=new List();
equipments = [Select id from Entitlement];

Error: Compile Error: sObject type 'Entitlement' is not supported.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are declaring the list correctly ?

```
List<Entitlement> entitlements = new List<Entitlement>();
entitlements = [Select Id From Entitlement];
```

Or you can do

```
List<Entitlement> entitlements = [Select Id From Entitlement];
```

Also have you [Enabled Entitlements](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=entitlements_enabling.htm&language=en_US) ?

Comment: I have declared list Correctly but it is throughing error

Comment: We have fixed the issue.It is throwing error because of version difference current my apex class is running under 15 version in 15th version Entitlement is not there.we have changedd to latest version